# Extraer texto de un archivo en R

Tags: array, r

Tengo un archivo .txt con una cadena de DNA de longitud fija y quiero que me devuelva un array de texto con distintos fragmentos.

La lectura del archivo la hago con el siguiente código:

```
dades<- read.table("DnaSeq.txt")
```

Ejemplo:

Tengo la cadena:

```
tgcaggctttgcacatgtgac
```

y quiero que me devuelva:

```
posicion valor
  1      tgc
  2      agg
  3      ctt
  4      tgc
  5      aca
  6      tgt
  7      gac
```

Solución:

```
dades<- read.table("DnaSeq.txt")
dades<-dades$V1
DNA <- substr(dades,0,3)
```

Comment: en vez de publicar la respuesta dentro de tu pregunta, y siguiendo el formato del sitio, ¿Podrías publicarlo como una respuesta, es decir abajo ?

Answer (score 1):

Esta función parece que funciona bien:

`aaa <- strsplit("la cadena que tienes", "(?<=.{3})", perl = TRUE)[[1]]`

luego creas un data.frame y ya está.

```
DNA <- data.frame("posicion" = seq(1,length(aaa)),
                  "valor" = aaa[1:length(aaa)])
```